# Simple Nodejs MongoDB Express iterate / loop collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to display a collection - insides mongo shell it is straight forward.

DB = testing
collection = inventory

```
> use testing
switched to db testing
> db.inventory.find();   // very easy and straight fwd
```

My problem is I can't seem to figure it out how to get a handle on the data as it iterates out.  I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mdb = require('mongoose');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoDB = "mongodb://localhost/testing";  

mdb.connect(mongoDB);
mdb.Promise = global.Promise;

let db = mdb.connection;

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    db.inventory.find(query).stream()
    .on('data', function(doc){
      // handle doc
      console.log("raw => " + doc);
      console.log("JSON => " + JSON.stringify(doc));
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log("Error: " + err)
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      console.log("iteration complete")
    });

});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If all you want to do is iterate over a collection, Mongoose is overkill.

Comment: Ok well what is the best to display search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this worked for me:
Database name: "testing"
Collection: "inventory"

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost/testing";  

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true },  function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let dbo = db.db("testing");

    var stream = dbo.collection("inventory").find().stream()
    stream.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err)
    })
    stream.on('data', function (doc) {
      console.log(doc)
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      // final callback
      console.log("iteration complete")
    });
  });

    //post blank page
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.end();
});
```